# How can I change taxonomy category default link structure to userfrindly one

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a custom post type called **video-list** and created a taxonomy called **video-category**.Now when i get term links it means category links with this code

```
$term_link = get_term_link($v_term, 'video-category');
```

here is the structure http://xxxxx/?video-category=mycategory.

But my single page url structure is http://xxxxx/videos/posttitle

Is it possible to remove the sign ? from the url and at the end create the following structure http://xxxxx/taxonomyname/categoryname?

Answer (score 0):

Found very simple solution.When registering the `taxonomy` I set the `rewrite` setting to `true` like this:

```
'rewrite' => true,
```

And with this links are more user-friendly without any signs.